# How to set default id in SQL form field type in Joomla

Tags: php, mysql, input, joomla

I have this field and I cant't set default id.
If I have category contacts, everthing works fine, but if categoryID(catid) is empty I get errors.
Any suggestions?

```
<field
                name="hr-category-contacts"
                type="sql"
                label="Select an HR partnern custom field"
                sql_select="e.*"
                sql_from="#__contact_details AS e"
                sql_where= "catid = 17"
                sql_group="name"
                sql_order="e.id ASC"
                key_field="id"
                value_field="name"
        />
```

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: https://docs.joomla.org/SQL_form_field_type